# Meteor and saving dropdown states

Tags: meteor

I have two collections 'Buckets' and 'Values' with two templates Bucket and Value, 'Bucket' renders a sub template 'Value'. Value is being updated every second by the server.
The Bucket template has two dropdowns which I'm keeping state in the corresponding Bucket model.

The problem I have is in firefox everytime I change a dropdown it saves the state but doesn't reflect the change in the template it instead goes to the last item in the dropdown list. If I refresh the state is reflected correctly.

I can fix it by creating a third collection called 'states' and save the dropdown states there with a corresponding reference back to the Bucket but would be nice not to have to do this.

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: Not able to understand your problem, please put some code blocks, if possible?

Answer (score 3):

Dropdowns are among the input elements that don't work quite right on 0.5.2.  There is currently a fix for this on the devel branch; you can either hang tight for a release, take your chances living on the edge, or find a workaround like putting your input element in a `{{#constant}}{{/constant}}` region.